# Angular 5: Subject's .next() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to push a new string to a Subject called **period** with .next() but the console gives me a *this.period.next is not a function* error.

**option.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-option',
    templateUrl: './option.component.html'
})
export class OptionComponent implements OnInit {
    public period: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    setPeriod(period: string) {
        this.period.next(period);
    }
}
```

**option.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="period" (ngModelChange)="setPeriod($event)">
    <span *ngFor="let option of httpHeader.option"><mat-radio-button [checked]="option.default" [value]="option.param" >{{ option.desc }}</mat-radio-button><br /></span>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I'm running rxjs 5.5.2. The function *setPeriod* is triggered when a user selects a radio button.

What am I doing wrong? I use the same method in a http service and that works but in this component it doesn't.

Comment: How is `setPeriod` called? Show template.

Comment: I've added the template.
Note: the .ts file is a stripped version

Comment: I believe `[(ngModel)]="period"` is overwriting your subject. What are you trying to do by assigning the subject to the radio group?

Comment: I'm trying to get the selected value from the radio buttons and put this value in a Subject so it can be accessed in a parent component.

Comment: @LLai Yes, that's it! Thank you

Comment: And don't put answers in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]="period"` is a two-way binding on your component's period property. I believe it's updating the `period` property to be equal to the radio group's value, overwriting the instance of Subject that you assign when the component is created. That's why it no longer has property `.next` when you call setPeriod.

The simple case usage of `mat-radio-group` in a template-driven form is this:

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group"
                 [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" 
                      *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
        {{season}}
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div class="example-selected-value">
    Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}
</div>

...
export class RadioNgModelExample {
    favoriteSeason: string;

    seasons = [
        'Winter',
        'Spring',
        'Summer',
        'Autumn',
    ];
}
```

Ref: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples

If you want to emit on a subject on every change to this radio group, I suggest you use reactive forms:

```
export class Example {
    radio: FormControl = new FormControl();
    period: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.radio.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            this.period.next(value);
        });
    }
}

<mat-radio-group [formControl]="radio">
    <span *ngFor="let option of httpHeader.option">
        <mat-radio-button [checked]="option.default" 
                          [value]="option.param" >
            {{ option.desc }}
        </mat-radio-button>
        <br />
   </span>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Thanks, but: 
`Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-radio-group'.`

Comment: You need to import the ReactiveFormsModule in the module your component is declared in.

Comment: @LLai was right: I'm overwriting the Subject period with `[(ngModel)]="period"` but your example works too!

Answer (score -1):

In Angular 2/4 usually the import is:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

I think, I hasn't changed in Angular 5

Also you are calling the function with an event as input parameter `"setPeriod($event)"` but the definition in code is a string `setPeriod(period: string)`

Comment: Thanks. Tested it but doesn't make a change.